# How to create sql user role which has full permission to read, write, delete and review all the objects in the database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to create sql user role which has full permission to read, write, delete and review all the objects in the database?

All objects - SP's, views,Tables, Functions, Triggers ....

It will be helpful to have the complete syntax . Not the GUI steps. I am able to do in GUI steps. I just need the syntax which will create the user role for the user from a SQL Job.

This is my current syntax, will that be helpful ...

```
CREATE USER [MyUser] FOR LOGIN [MyUser]  
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [MyUser]  
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [MyUser]  
go
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the role db_owner already covers these specific needs.

Comment: When you make a change using SSMS, you have the option to save those changes as a script. That allows you to look at the commands SSMS generates to do something. You should also think about what you ask. Those permissions to not apply to "all objects". You don't read procedures, you execute them. And if you've already assigned permissions to a user/role, then use the scripting options for that user/role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Use masters; 

CREATE SERVER ROLE role_name AUTHORIZATION sysadmin;  
GO
```

The sysadmin has the full permission to read, write, delete and review all the objects in the database.

Here is the reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-server-role?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: This is my current syntax ..    will that be helpful .. CREATE USER [MyUser] FOR LOGIN [MyUser]  
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [MyUser]  
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [MyUser]  
go

Comment: Yes, your syntax is right. But if [MyUser] has [db_owner] role membership, he can do anything inside the database. No need to add [db_datareader].

Comment: thank you...  Now let's say .. if  i need to limit the user by giving Read only access .. that is to read the tables .. and view the stored procedures .. but not to delete any records .. in that case.. can i give only db_reader.  Challenge is, when i give only db_reader.. users are not able to see the stored procedures.. please correct me

Comment: and also, i am not going to create server role as sysadmin. only db_owner. Please correct me, whether i need to give sysadmin also ???

Comment: @goofyui If you only give them [db_datareader],  the users are able to issue a SELECT statement against all tables and views in the database. The users cannot delete any records but they can see the stored procedures. One simple example is 'select * from sys.procedures'.

Comment: @goofyui If you want to grant 'execute' permission to the user for one specific stored procedure: GRANT EXECUTE ON [usp_StoredProcedureName] TO [MyUser]

Comment: Thanks  a lot.. last question is .. the syntax which we are applying will automatically applied to all the databases in the server (or) it will be specific to database mapped on user profile settings ?

Comment: @goofyui. It is on the database level. But if you want to create some new roles, that would be on the server level.

Comment: I believe only for the databases mapped on the user profile will be impacted .., thanks ..